# Does WeasyPrint support footnotes?

Tags: html, pdf, weasyprint

I understand it is CSS based on the documentation I've read about it. I am not able to figure out if it supports footnotes or not? 
Here is what I was referring to, http://weasyprint.org/docs/features/#css Do you think its a bad idea to hardcode a footer in? For example, make a div and add items to that?

Currently all I want to do is convert my HTML file to a PDF file. I am currently using wkhtmltopdf but since it is not CSS based (and doesnt support footnotes), I am thinking of switching out.

Comment: Http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf has a footnote inplementation. See the samples

Comment: But it isn't something internal. It works by external service. I need only internal :(

Comment: Well you can certainly implement your own cloudformatter server if you want one, but it is not free

Answer (score 0):

For visitors from the future...

Based on this closed [issue](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/298) and the [docs](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/api_reference.html#css-generated-content-for-paged-media-module), yes it does!